# Using `min_active_rowversion` for global temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporary-tables

I use global temporary tables for easy integration testing of my SQL Server backed application.

But the function `min_active_rowversion` does not seem to include global temporary tables, like seen here:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    connection.Open();

    connection.Execute("create table ##mytable ( Id int, rv rowversion )");

    var a = ToUInt64(connection.Query<byte[]>("select min_active_rowversion()").Single()); // => 20001

    var x = ToUInt64(connection.Query<byte[]>("insert into ##mytable (Id) output Inserted.rv values (1)").Single()); // => 22647

    var b = ToUInt64(connection.Query<byte[]>("select min_active_rowversion()").Single()); // => 20001
}
```

I can't see this limitation documented anywhere. Can this be made to work? And if so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The explanation would appear to be that the global temporary table is in fact in TempDB, not the database your code is running against. This is because the [MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-active-rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function is scoped to the database level.

The min_active_rowversion() function seems to work when you use the following code

```
USE [db]

CREATE table ##mytable ( Id int, rv rowversion )

USE [tempdb]

select min_active_rowversion()

insert into ##mytable (Id) values (1)

select min_active_rowversion()

insert into ##mytable (Id) values (1)

select min_active_rowversion()
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=434ac2ec10e6384cbb0ebdb49871a0ad)